# Kotlin Coroutine throws JobCancellationException and trigger observers

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm implementing `kotlin coroutines` in `MVVM` architecture in order to replace my `RxJava` dependency.

**My problem**:
After logging out (this detail is important because I don't have the exception on a fresh start), I have a `JobCancellationException` coroutine exception thrown on the launch of the `viewModelScope` **AND** all of my `observers` in the LoginActivity are triggered (wtf ?) even if the `try/catch` block is not executed (breakpoint) so it totally breaks my code logic.

**My layers are as follows**:
`Activity`, `setOnClickListener` triggered, call `viewModel` function **->** `ViewModel`, create `coroutine` within `viewModelScope` and call `suspend function` **->** `Repository`, `suspended function` called from `viewModel` and call a `suspend function` in `ApiService` **->** `suspend function` that makes the Api call

**Usecase**:
I log in my app freshly started (`LoginActivity`). My stack is cleared to start the `MainActivity`. I go to the `SettingsActivity` to logout. I logout and clear the stack once again to start a brand new `LoginActivity`. And when I try to login again I have the `exception` thrown and my `observers` are triggered.

LoginActivty:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        tvLogin.setSafeOnClickListener { login() }
}
private fun login() {
        Firebase.analytics.logEvent("hit_login", null)
        runOnUiThread {
            pDialog = SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE)
            pDialog!!.progressHelper.barColor = Color.parseColor("#2A6022")
            pDialog!!.titleText =
                "<font color='#2A6022'>" + resources.getString(R.string.signing) + "</font>"
            pDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
        }
        var pwd = etPassword.text.toString()
        if (passedBiometric) {
            pwd = sessionManager.decrypt(sessionManager.loadUsername())
        }
        passedBiometric = false
        viewModel.login(etUsername.text.toString(), pwd)
        viewModel.error.observe(this, {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(it), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
        viewModel.loadingState.observe(this, {
        Timber.e("LoadingState Observer triggered")
            when (it) {
                LoadingState.LOADED -> {
                    pDialog!!.dismiss()
                    Timber.e("LOADED")
                    startMainActivity()
                }
                LoadingState.FAILED -> {
                    pDialog!!.dismiss()
                    Timber.e("FAILED")
                    viewModel.error.value?.let { errorRsc ->
                        Toast.makeText(this, getString(errorRsc), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                LoadingState.LOADING -> {
                    pDialog!!.show()
                    Timber.e("LOADING")
                }
            }
        })
  }

private fun startMainActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    intent.action = this.intent.action
    intent.putExtra(ProfileFragment.USER, viewModel.user.value)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel(private val repo: ApiRepository, private val sessionManager: SessionManager) :
    ViewModel() {
    private val _error = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val error: LiveData<Int>
        get() = _error
    private val _loadingState = MutableLiveData<LoadingState>()
    val loadingState: LiveData<LoadingState>
        get() = _loadingState
    private val token = MutableLiveData<SessionToken>()
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User>
        get() = _user

fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    try {
        Timber.e("enter try block outside viewModelScope.launch")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                Timber.e("try block inside viewModelScope.launch")
                _loadingState.value = LoadingState.LOADING
                token.value = repo.login(username, password)
                sessionManager.storeSessionToken(token.value!!.token)
                sessionManager.storeUsername(username)
                sessionManager.encrypt(username, password)
                _user.value = repo.getUser()
                _loadingState.value = LoadingState.LOADED
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e("catch block inside viewModelScope.launch")
                if (e is HttpException) {
                    when (e.code()) {
                        500, 503 -> {
                            _error.value = R.string.error_api_down
                        }
                        400 -> {
                            _error.value = R.string.error_bad_credentials
                        }
                    }
                }
                _loadingState.value = LoadingState.FAILED
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e: Exception){
        Timber.e("Catch block outside viewmodelScope.launch")
        when (e){
            is CancellationException -> { Timber.e("CancellationException caught")}
            else -> { Timber.e("Unknown caught")}
        }
    }
}

}
```

ApiRepository:

```
class ApiRepository(
    private val apiService: ApiService,
    private val sessionManager: SessionManager
) {
    suspend fun login(username: String, password: String): SessionToken {
        val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
        map["username"] = username
        map["password"] = password
        return apiService.login(
            JSONObject(map.toMap()).toString()
                .toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        )
    }

    suspend fun getUser(): User {
        return apiService.getUser(sessionManager.loadSessionToken())
    }

}
```

ApiService:

```
interface ApiService {
    companion object {
        private const val AUTH = "Authorization"
    }
    @POST(ApiRouting.URL_TOKEN)
    suspend fun login(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): SessionToken
    @GET(ApiRouting.URL_GET_USER)
    suspend fun getUser(@Header(AUTH) token: String): User

}
```

SettingsActivity:

```
private fun initListeners() {
    tvLogout.setSafeOnClickListener {
        DashboardManager.clearValues()
        sessionManager.clearSessionToken()
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

**TLDR: Why the exception is thrown ? Why the observers are triggered ? And Why is this situation only occurs after a logout and not on fresh start ?**

I tried to add coroutineScope in the launch and another scope in the repository with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` but it didn't change anything

I'm a very beginner in `kotlin coroutines` so if you have any suggestion, link or whatever that might help welcome. Or if you need any other block of code let me know.

**EDIT**:
I added several log (`LoginViewModel` and `MainActivity`) to detail when I enter in try catch block that surround my `viewModelScope.launch` and when my `MainActivity` start (next action after my `observer` is triggered in the `LoginAvtivity`.

To let you see more visibility on what a fresh (and successful) start looks like:

```
E/LoginViewModel: enter try block outside viewModelScope.launch
E/LoginViewModel$login: try block inside viewModelScope.launch
E/LoginActivity$login: LoadingState Observer triggered
V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
E/LoginActivity$login: LOADING
    LoadingState Observer triggered
    LOADING
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST http://45.153.184.141/api-token-auth/
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 46
    --> END POST (46-byte body)
E/LoginActivity$login: LoadingState Observer triggered
    LOADING
D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@7175d32[LoginActivity]
W/Choreographer: Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
W/Choreographer: Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 OK http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api-token-auth/ (237ms)
    Date: Wed, 03 Mar 2021 21:31:39 GMT
    Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.2
    Content-Type: application/json
    Allow: POST, OPTIONS
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Content-Length: 52
    Vary: Cookie
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    <-- END HTTP (52-byte body)
W/r.myweedmanage: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/r.myweedmanage: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/r.myweedmanage: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREPERF for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lDY2traUg4aTJaQVJ3T3MxTEV6RktsZDE1YU9HOG96S28=) with jobId=877081683 in 30000ms(Backend next call timestamp 1614807010307). Attempt 1
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET http://45.153.184.141/api/users/profile/
    Authorization: Token token
    --> END GET
D/OnePlusJankManager:  Chor uploadMDM JANK_TYPE_ONCE mViewTitle = com.weedmanager.myweedmanager/com.weedmanager.myweedmanager.authentication.LoginActivity--- jank level = 1
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 OK http://45.153.184.141/api/users/profile/ (83ms)
    Date: Wed, 03 Mar 2021 21:31:40 GMT
    Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.2
    Content-Type: application/json
    Vary: Accept
    Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Content-Length: 103
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    <-- END HTTP (103-byte body)
W/r.myweedmanage: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/r.myweedmanage: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/LoginActivity$login: LoadingState Observer triggered
W/r.myweedmanage: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
E/LoginActivity$login: LOADED
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREPERF for destination cct
D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@4a8ec73[LoginActivity]
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lDY2traUg4aTJaQVJ3T3MxTEV6RktsZDE1YU9HOG96S28=) is already scheduled. Returning...
E/LoginActivity$login: LoadingState Observer triggered
    LOADED
E/LoginActivity$login: LoadingState Observer triggered
    LOADED
D/OnePlusJankManager:  Chor uploadMDM JANK_TYPE_ONCE mViewTitle = com.weedmanager.myweedmanager/com.weedmanager.myweedmanager.authentication.LoginActivity--- jank level = 1
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1494
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c6ecc8e
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1057027342
D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
V/FA: onActivityCreated
E/MainActivity: MainActivity onCreate
```

Now after a log out when the magic occurs:

```
E/LoginViewModel: enter try block outside viewModelScope.launch
D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
E/LoginActivity$login: LoadingState Observer triggered
E/LoginActivity$login: LOADED
V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 8496
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1057275561
W/Choreographer: Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@24faad3
E/MainActivity: MainActivity onCreate
```

So we can clearly see that it doesn't enter in the `try` block inside the `viewModelScope.launch` because the log is not displayed and the request are not made (`profiler` empty too) but no `Exception` is caught in the `try/catch` block that surrounds `viewModelScope.launch`

Indeed I discovered the `JobCancellationException` when I debugged my code with `breakpoint` and `step over`.

I tried to change my scope by changing from `viewModelScope.launch` to `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch` (just to test with this scope according to the comment below the question) and it's crashing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you call coroutineScope right after viewModelScope.launch? I don't think you need it. What you could do instead is try using supervisorScope instead of coroutineScope

Comment: Error handling in coroutines is a normal flow, so the JobCancellation is likely coming from your try, and you aren't handling it so it is falling through. I don't see any other potential cancellations at first glance. Giuseppe is right, no need for coroutineScope after launch, though I don't think a different scope would fix this.

Comment: @GiuseppeGiacoppo I forgot to remove it, it was indeed a test to see if it would affect the exception in any way...

Comment: I removed the coroutineScop additionally added, it was a test. Do you have any idea on how to handle the JobCancellation ? I tried to launch the viewmodel.login() inside a try/catch block and the catch is not triggered... @BenjaminCharais

Comment: It would seem not triggered because the context of a coroutine is elevated to where it is started, that's where you'd get the error. So instead you'd need a try/catch around the launch

Comment: could you share the stacktrace when JobCancellationException is thrown?

Comment: Exception is not caught @BenjaminCharais check the edited code with log and try/catch block.

Comment: Stracktrace added @GiuseppeGiacoppo if you need more verbose or debug let me know.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Component scopes (viewModelScope) and I wonder if the ViewModel lifecycle is out of sync with the work you are expecting, which could mean that scope is inaccessible. What if you used a different coroutineScope? For example: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch ---  If you're modifying any viewModel values, you would have to switch back to the viewModel scope... but if that change even gets into the coroutine, you know the issue is tied with your lifecycles being in an unexpected state

Comment: yes I join you on the scope being inaccessible because of the viewModel state, it explains why the problem occurs after a logout and not on a fresh start. But indeed I modify my viewModel values so I'm wondering what can I do to fix the problem efficiently. @BenjaminCharais

Comment: You would need to make sure that the viewModel is initialized in a logout path. Since it is seemingly destructed, maybe just initialize it in the login to verify it has an accessible scope no matter what while attempting the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem. Indeed I'm using `Koin` for `dependency injection`.
I simply replaced single:

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    single { StatsViewModel(get()) }
    single{ LoginViewModel(get(), get()) }
}
```

by viewModel:

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { StatsViewModel(get()) }
    viewModel { LoginViewModel(get(), get()) }
}
```

Indeed, single makes a singleton so by using the `viewModel` keyword, the `viewModel` is bound to the Android Component lifecycle.

https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel/

Comment: That was a blunder mistake . You never make a Singelton `ViewMode`l its defeats the whole purpose of having `ViewModel`. Its great you found it on your own.

Comment: Indeed, it's the first time I'm using Koin so I wasn't aware of the viewModel keyword..

Answer (score 0):

So, In my case I was using liveData builder,
and at the observer end after receiving a single value I was removing the observer,
so at the time when remove observer called, the coroutine of livedata builder was cancelled, JobCancellationException was thrown, so the solution was pretty simple, I called remove observer when I get new live data so for previous one we can use remove oberserver.